# How to add static HTML before and after jquery prependTo inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach, each

I have and array and looping through jQuery $.each to iterate and creating html dom elements on the fly and prepending it to the DOM.

```
  $.each(res, function(key, ele){
        var stemtext = ele[0];
        var stemID = ele[1];
        var pageNo = ele[2];            
        //Build HTML here
        $('<div/>', {
            'id':stemID,
            'class':'text-paragraph',
            'style':'cursor:pointer;',
            'html': '<p style="width: 80%; float: left;">'+ stemtext +'</p><p style="width:20%; float:left">'+ stemID +'</p>'
        }).prependTo('#PlaceHolder');
    });
```

This code works flawlessly.

But I need to add some static HTML before and after this generated HTML in $.each loop & then prepend it. I have to do this in jQuery only, can't touch HTML.

I tried storing this html to a variable and then adding the HTML, but didn't work,

What is the best way to add some static HTML before and after the generated HTML inside $.each loop?

Comment: What HTML are you trying to add? `before()`, `after()`, `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` would work depending on your need.

Comment: Oh.. Is that this simple.. let me try. This is html I am trying to add before <div class="text-paragraph"><p style="width: 80%; float: left; font-weight: bold;">Question Text </p><p style="width:20%; float:left; font-weight: bold;">Option Choosen</p></div>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get your problem, but with what i understoood, there is my solution (i'm sure there is better way to do it) :

```
 $('<div/>', {
        'id':"todelete",
    }).prependTo('#PlaceHolder');


   $('<div/>', {
        'id':"stemID",
        'class':'text-paragraph',
        'style':'cursor:pointer;',
        'html': '<p style="width: 80%; float: left;">stem text</p><p style="width:20%; float:left">stemID</p>'
    }).prependTo('#todelete');

    $('<div/>', {
        'id':"elementBefore",
        'class':'text-paragraph',
        'style':'cursor:pointer;',
        'html': '<p>Before place holder</p>'
    }).prependTo('#todelete');

    $('<div/>', {
        'id':"elementAfter",
        'class':'text-paragraph',
        'style':'cursor:pointer;',
        'html': '<p >After place holder</p>'
    }).appendTo('#todelete');

    $("#stemID").unwrap();
```

LIVE DEMO [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v571oatq/)